# Split string in R

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, strsplit

I am trying to split the output of "ls -lrt" command from Linux. but it's taking only one space as delimeter. If there is two space then its taking 2nd space as value. So I think I need to suppress multiple space as one. Does anybody has any idea on this?

```
> a <- try(system("ls -lrt | grep -i .rds", intern = TRUE))
> a
[1] "-rw-r--r-- 1 u7x9573 sashare  2297 Jun  9 16:10 abcde.RDS"
[2] "-rw-r--r-- 1 u7x9573 sashare 86704 Jun  9 16:10 InputSource2.rds"
> str(a)
chr [1:6] "-rw-r--r-- 1 u7x9573 sashare  2297 Jun  9 16:10 abcde.RDS" ...
>
>c = strsplit(a," ")
>c
[[1]]
 [1] "-rw-r--r--" "1"          "u7x9573"    "sashare"    ""
 [6] "2297"       "Jun"        ""           "9"          "16:10"
 [11] "abcde.RDS"

[[2]]
 [1] "-rw-r--r--"       "1"                "u7x9573"          "sashare"
 [5] "86704"            "Jun"              ""                 "9"
 [9] "16:10"            "InputSource2.rds"
```

In next step I needed just file name and I used following code which worked fine:

```
mtrl_name <- try(system("ls | grep -i .rds", intern = TRUE))
```

Comment: What is the exact result you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns that info in a data frame for the indicated files:

```
file.info(list.files(pattern = "[.]rds$", ignore.case = TRUE))
```

or if we knew the extensions were lower case:

```
file.info(Sys.glob("*.rds"))
```

Comment: Only problem with this was to receive the file name, otherwise it is ok. For file name I used > mtrl_name <- try(system("ls | grep -i .rds", intern = TRUE))

Comment: The rownames of the resulting data frame hold the file names. `fi <- file.info(Sys.glob("*.rds")); rownames(fi)`

Answer (score 2):

strsplit takes a regular expression so we can use those to help out.  For more info read `?regex`

```
> x <- "Spaces   everywhere right?  "
> # Not what we want
> strsplit(x, " ")
[[1]]
[1] "Spaces"     ""           ""           "everywhere" "right?"    
[6] ""          

> # Use " +" to tell it to split on 1 or more space
> strsplit(x, " +")
[[1]]
[1] "Spaces"     "everywhere" "right?"  
> # If we want to be more explicit and catch the possibility of tabs, new lines, ...
> strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]+")
[[1]]
[1] "Spaces"     "everywhere" "right?"
```

Comment: ...and `strsplit(x, "\\s+")` as another alternative.